# FFT for n Points (non power of 2 )

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I need to know a way to make FFT (DFT) work with just n points, where n is not a power of 2.

I want to analyze an modify the sound spectrum, in particular of Wave-Files, which have in common 44100 sampling points. But my FFT does not work, it only works with points which are in shape like 2^n.

So what can I do? Beside fill up the vector with zeros to the next power of 2 ?!
Any way to modify the FFT algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate on Math.StackExchange http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77118

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the math foundations of an algorithm, and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77118 already has good answers to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from padding the array as you suggest, or using some other library function, you can construct a Fourier transform with arbitrary length and spacing in the frequency domain (also for non-integer sample spacings).

This is a well know result and is based on the Chirp-z transform ([or Bluestein's FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestein%27s_FFT_algorithm)). Another good reference is given by Rabiner and can be found at the above link.

In summary, with this approach you don't have to write the FFT yourself, you can simply use an existing high-performance FFT and then apply the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) to a suitably scaled and conditioned version of your signal.

The performance will still be, O(n*log n), multiplied by some implementation-dependent scaling factor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the FFTW library or the code generators of the Spiral project. They implement FFT for numbers with small prime factors, break down large prime factors p by reducing it to a FFT of size (p-1) which is even, etc.

However, just for signal analysis it is questionable why you want to analyze exactly one second of sound and not smaller units. Also, you may want to use a windowing procedure to avoid the jumps at the ends of the segment.

Answer (score 0):

The FFT is just a faster method of computing the DFT for certain length vectors; and a DFT can be computed for any length of input vector.  You can also zero-pad your input vector to a length supported by your FFT library, which may be faster.

If you want to modify your sound file, you may need to use the overlap-add or overlap-save fast convolution filtering after determining the length of the impulse response of your frequency domain modification.